# Why does PHP tell me this variable isn't defined?

Tags: php, variables, laravel, undefined

I'm trying to filter some logs like I need them and tried to it dynamic. I have some domains and I'm trying to filter some things from it, and it all works like I want it - but now I changed the domain name and now my code doesn't work anymore. It says one variable isn't defined.

```
      $sp_bots = shell_exec("grep bot | awk '{print $12}' /var/www/laravel/logs/vhosts/domain.log");
    $array_sp_bots = explode("\n", $sp_bots);
    $all_bots = array();
    foreach($array_sp_bots as $bots){
        if(strpos($bots, "bot")){
            $all_bots[] = $bots;
        }
    }
    # count values of strings in array
    if (!empty( $all_bots )) {
        $bots = array_count_values($all_bots);
        arsort($bots);
        $mostOccuring = max(array_count_values($all_bots));
        $bot_keys = array_keys($bots);
        #number of total bots
        $count_bots = count($all_bots);
    }
```

and in my returns:

```
return view('/domains/data', [

       'count_bots' => $count_bots,
        'bot_keys' => $bot_keys,
        'mostOccuring' => $mostOccuring,
    ]);
```

but all three variables in my return are undefined.. anybody knows why?

Comment: What was the output of $sp_bots after changing the domain?

Comment: define $all_bots like $all_bots = array(); above foreach

Comment: Because you're never defining `$all_bots`, just assuming that it already exists when you do `$all_bots[] = $bots;`

Comment: thanks but now i get this from php : max(): Array must contain at least one element

Comment: While `$all_bots[] = $bots;` will define `$all_bots` it does it under protest by issuing a warning message because strictly speaking you're ___modifying__ `$all_bots` in that statement

Comment: so and how do i fix that? I'm kinda new in php..

Comment: okay got it - Moppo helped me there.. but know it sais $count_bots isnt defined..

Comment: i updated my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize the array as an empty array before the loop:

```
$all_bots = array();          //init the empty array

foreach($array_sp_bots as $bots)
{
    if(strpos($bots, "bot"))
    {
        $all_bots[] = $bots;  //here you can add elements to the array
    }
}
```

in your case, if the loop does not execute at least one time, the variable `$all_bots` will be undefined

**EDIT**

After the loop, to handle the case when the array is empty do somthing like this:

```
//if there is some element in all_bots...
if ( ! empty( $all_bots ) )
{
    # count values of strings in array
    $bots = array_count_values($all_bots);
    arsort($bots);
    $mostOccuring = max(array_count_values($all_bots));
    $bot_keys = array_keys($bots);
    #number of total bots
    $count_bots = count($all_bots);
}
//handle the case the variable all_bots is empty
else
{
    $bots = 0;
    $count_bots = 0;
    $bot_keys = 0;
    $mostOccuring = 0;
}
```

**EDIT2**

You have the variables undefined in your return because when all `$all_bots` is empty they are not set. Check my edit above, i have added them to the if statement. But you have to handle this case in your application according to your needs, think this way: What these variables should contain when `$all_bots` is empty? Then assign the values to the variables in the if statement

Comment: yes, because you're trying to get the max value from an empty array, check my edit

Comment: okay this works fine thanks :) but know i have the problem that it sais: Undefined variable: count_bots -- but i defining it right here:

$count_bots = count($all_bots); 

is it because of $all_bots or why?

Comment: it's strange as `$count_bots` can't be undefined, where are you accessing the variable ?

Comment: in my return is written :             'count_bots' => $count_bots,
            'bot_keys' => $bot_keys,
            'mostOccuring' => $bot_keys,
---
ErrorException in LogController.php line 134: - thats 134 - all three variables are undefined - $count_bots, $bot_keys, $bot_keys,

Comment: if it says: `Undefined variable: count_bots` php is trying to access the variable `count_bots`, where are you accessing it ? In a following section of code that is not posted ?

Comment: please edit your question posting the code where you're getting the error

Comment: okay i did - please look at my question :) I'm sorry for all this.. :)

Comment: check my second edit. I suggest you to try to understand what is going on in the code: it's only a matter of accessing a bunch of variables that could be empty

Comment: thanks for this :) this works now.. thank god :) i'm trying to handle my future problems first at my own :) 

and sorry for my bad english.. I'm from germany :)

Comment: no problem, i think it would be useful for you to learn the basics of arrays, if statement, and variables assignment

Comment: i will yes :) but can i ask you one more think? 

the code 'works' - the variables are defined but there isnt in there.. 

what i mean is :



       foreach ($array_sp_bots as $bots) {
            if (strpos($bots, "bot")) {
                $all_bots[] = $bots;
            }
        }



----- 


after the foreach - there isnt something in $all_bots and so nothing in $bots..

in my foreach i did a return $bots - else return "failed" - and it failed..

Comment: it was cause i was searching for "bot" - but the bot is names : "Bot" - :) thanks for everything :)

Comment: no problem...remember to accept / upvote if it was useful :)

Comment: @Evolution48: please consider accepting the answers if they are useful to you (i see from your profile that you never accept them, but it would be a good way to thanks the users for their effort to provide you some help )

Answer (score 2):

It is happening because after changing the domain it is not executing inside the loop. Try with -

```
$all_bots= array(); // Define an empty array
foreach($array_sp_bots as $bots){
    if(strpos($bots, "bot")){
        $all_bots[] = $bots;
    }
}
# count values of strings in array
$bots = array_count_values($all_bots);
```

If the `$array_sp_bots` is empty then it would not execute the loop & `$all_bots` would not be defined. For that case the count would be `0`.

Or may might want to add some check for that -

```
if(empty($all_bots)) {
    // Some error message
} else {
    # count values of strings in array
    $bots = array_count_values($all_bots);
    arsort($bots);
    $mostOccuring = max(array_count_values($all_bots));
    $bot_keys = array_keys($bots);
    #number of total bots
    $count_bots = count($all_bots);
}
```

Comment: thanks but now i get this from php : max(): Array must contain at least one element

Comment: Check the update. The rest of the code should be executed only it is not empty.

Comment: Iäm returning my variables to my view but all 3 variables are undefined..

            'count_bots' => $count_bots,
            'bot_keys' => $bot_keys,
            'mostOccuring' => $mostOccuring,